# Need namespace for data stored with @ngxs/storage-plugin

Tags: ngxs

I have several instances of an angular app that are hosted on the same server (with different base-hrefs like `https://my.server/app0`, `https://my.server/app1`, ...).

I tried to persist my ngxs state using the @ngxs/storage-plugin, but i cannot find an option to define a prefix or namespace for my data to prevent the different app-instances to interfere with each other.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this properly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that using the [Custom Storage Engine](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage#custom-storage-engine) of `@ngxs/storage-plugin`, by implementing your own storage engine and adding a prefix (that refers to your app instance) to the stored key.